# Attempting to move around iframe in DOM without refreshing. Chrome's "adoptNode" seems to not be working

Tags: dom, google-chrome, iframe

Here is the deal (over-simplified a bit)
I'm creating an application which has "tabs", each tab can have similar content displayed as iFrames.
So, I was hoping to share those in between tab switches, since the initial request from the iFrame load is somewhat of an expensive operation.

This, however, would require me to "save" the iframe, and then re-insert on the DOM.
There are two issues with that:
1) I can't seem to be able to access the iframe's contentWindow to call into javascript functions while it's resting in memory
2) The iframe reloads whenever it's inserted in the DOM.

I read that document.adoptNode might fix issue #2, so I tried the following

```
<html> 
 <head> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
  <script> 

    window.onload = function() {
            setTimeout(adoptIFrame, 500);
        };

    var next = ['red', 'blue']
    var index = 0;

    function adoptIFrame() {
        var iFrame = document.adoptNode(document.getElementById("frame")); 
        document.getElementById(next[index++ % 2]).appendChild(iFrame) 
        setTimeout(adoptIFrame, 500);
    }

  </script> 

    <div id="red" style="width:500;height:500;background-color:red;">
    </div>
    <div id="blue" style="width:500;height:500;background-color:blue;">
        <iframe src="your_url" id="frame"/>
    </div>

   </body>
```

But each time, there is a still a refresh being made on re-insertion.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit late, but since I've come across the same issue, I did some research and it seems the feature has been removed from Webkit: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=81590.